# How to separating arrays in php?

Tags: php

I get array data with this format:

For example:

```
array = [
    "index-category",
    "create-category",
    "store-category",
    "show-category",
    "index-products",
    "create-products",
    "store-products",
    "show-products",
    "edit-products",
    "index-sales",
    "create-sales",
]
```

I need convert to :

```
array {
    0 => {
         "index-category",
         "create-category",
         "store-category",
         "show-category",
    },
    1 => {
         "index-products",
         "create-products",
         "store-products",
         "show-products",
         "edit-products",
    }
    2 => {
         "index-sales",
         "create-sales",
    }
}
```

How to convert to this array?

Is php a method that automatically converts ?

Comment: No, there is no function to do this. You need to write your own.

Comment: No automatic function. But pretty simple requirement: Loop original, explode value, check `exploded[0]`, push to new array if new, push to existing index of new array otherwise.

Comment: square brackets / round brackets - not curly ;)

Comment: @TimLewis Hi, Please write example. Thanks

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Hi, Please write example. Thanks

Comment: No. Show what you've done first and I could correct any issues with your code, but I'm not writing it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just mess up with proper array notation here. Array notation no uses curly braces `{` or `}`. So If it is a proper array then you can try like this way using [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

**N.B** : For array notation we can use two different ways e.g `$array = []` or `$array=array()`

```
<?php
$array = [
    'category.index',
    'category.create',
    'category.store',
    'category.edit',
    'product.index',
    'product.create',
    'product.store',
    'product.edit',
    'city.index',
    'city.create',
    'city.store',
    'city.edit',
];
print '<pre>';
print_r(array_chunk($array,4));
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => category.index
            [1] => category.create
            [2] => category.store
            [3] => category.edit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product.index
            [1] => product.create
            [2] => product.store
            [3] => product.edit
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => city.index
            [1] => city.create
            [2] => city.store
            [3] => city.edit
        )

)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/980164

**EDIT:**

> AS PER YOUR QUESTION UPDATE

Simply try like this with [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
    list($item, $number) = explode('.', $val);
    $new[$item][] = $val;
}

print '<pre>';
print_r(array_values($new));
print '</pre>';
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/980176

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => category.index
            [1] => category.create
            [2] => category.store
            [3] => category.edit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product.index
            [1] => product.create
            [2] => product.store
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => city.index
            [1] => city.create
            [2] => city.store
            [3] => city.edit
        )

)
```

**EDITED AGAIN**

As you've different initial array on your question now so now code should be like this.

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
    list($item, $number) = explode('-', $val);
    $new[$number][] = $val;
}

print '<pre>';
print_r(array_values($new));
print '</pre>';
```

**DEMO:**  https://eval.in/980251

Comment: I'm assuming they want it split by the first part of the string, i.e. `product` and `city` not just every 4 elements.

Comment: Hi, My question is update. In array is example.

Comment: Technically correct; better hope the array is static/already in the right order though.

Comment: @Wreigh see my latest edit. It should work for you as you changed the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a simple algorithm to convert the input data:

```
<?php
$input = [
    'category.index',
    'category.create',
    'category.store',
    'category.edit',
    'product.index',
    'product.create',
    'product.store',
    'city.index',
    'city.create',
    'city.store',
    'city.edit',
];

$category = [];
array_walk($input, function ($entry) use (&$category) {
    $tokens = explode('.', $entry);
    $category[$tokens[0]][] = $entry;
});
$output = array_values($category);
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => category.index
            [1] => category.create
            [2] => category.store
            [3] => category.edit
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => product.index
            [1] => product.create
            [2] => product.store
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => city.index
            [1] => city.create
            [2] => city.store
            [3] => city.edit
        )
)
```

---

Here is the same algorithm with a trivial modification to match the changed input data you now suddenly presented by updating the question and commenting to this answer.

As already mentioned before in the comments all this does not really affect the algorithm, tiny adjustments will again deliver the desired output:

```
<?php
$input = [
    "index-category",
    "create-category",
    "store-category",
    "show-category",
    "index-products",
    "create-products",
    "store-products",
    "show-products",
    "edit-products",
    "index-sales",
    "create-sales",
];

$category = [];
array_walk($input, function ($entry) use (&$category) {
    $tokens = explode('-', $entry);
    $category[$tokens[1]][] = $entry;
});
$output = array_values($category);
print_r($output);
```

This will, as expected, result in that output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => index-category
            [1] => create-category
            [2] => store-category
            [3] => show-category
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => index-products
            [1] => create-products
            [2] => store-products
            [3] => show-products
            [4] => edit-products
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => index-sales
            [1] => create-sales
        )
)
```

Comment: Hi, My question is update. In array is example.

Comment: @Wreigh I don't the the difference. You removed an entry from the input. Sure, does not matter for the algorithm I posted. The output will be as expected.

Comment: @Wreigh I updated the answer to match the exact input data you gave in the question (so with a removed entry in the second category). As said: this does not change a thing. Obviously now the output contains one entry less too...

Comment: Thank you. I run rhis code but show this error: `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: @Wreigh Sorry, but the code I posted is correct. You most likely did _not_ run that code but something you adapted. So you made a mistake in adapting what I posted. I suspect your input data is actually different from what you posted...

Comment: Thank you, I update my question. please check again.

Comment: @Wreigh Is this question a joke? Why don't you know what input data you have? Please, for future questions, take the time to prepare your question, what we currently experience is annoying for everyone for no reason at all. Anyway, I updated the answer again and added a slightly modified version which, unsurprisingly, delivers the desired result...

Comment: @Wreigh And now I see that you even accepted that other answer which is a copy from my code... Pffffft

Comment: Why ? Down voted on my answer :P,  I didn't copy your answer @arkascha , you can clearly see my answer is different from yours. By the way I just add/edit my answer as OP changes the question without even looking on your solution

Comment: @BeingSunny I down voted your answer now, indeed. Do not get this wrong. That is not because I envy you or anything. However your answer does not answer the OPs question at all now. That was updated _again_ and now shows completely different input. I indeed was frustrated when I once more updated my answer to match that again changed input data only to find out that the OP comment that change to my answer _after_ having had accepted your answer. Which is a really ridiculous thing to do.

Comment: @arkascha However your answer does not answer the OPs question at all now. So I've updated it again with simple tweak but I m not frustrated and didn't say anything like "that answer is copy of my answer" or didn't downvoted  indeed.

Comment: @BeingSunny No, you did not down vote my answer, why should you? It was valid all the time, from the beginning, whereas you had to completely rewrite your answer to the current state which reflects _exactly_ what I posted long before you made that update. Anyway, I removed my down vote from your answer, since your answer _now_ answers the question again. Seems you envy something in the end, considering the tone of your comments...

Comment: @BeingSunny BTW, when you gather more experience on this site you will learn that points are not relevant. You want 5000 points from me? Sure. I have no issue with that. I am here to help others, not for stupid points...

Comment: @arkascha, no no plz don't misunderstood me. My tone is not envious and I m very beginner in front of you(so i shouldn't dare to envy you). One more thing I didn't completely rewrite the whole thing I just keep updating my answer as per the the input changes from OP. Simple index  change after explode. Thanks sir...

Comment: From the beginning I just want to make sure that I didn't copy your answer because I didn't see answers on SO while coding. Hope I am not sounding envious :)